# Blank map MapType wanted in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to find a way of producing a solid color map in Google Maps v3 API, making that another selection in my drop-down MapTypes menu.  My understanding is that was possible with v2 using MAP_TYPE_NONE, but I can't find a comparable functionality in v3.

I find I can produce gray background using

```
MaptypeTypes.push(new gmaps.ags.MapType("http://",{name:'No map'}));
```

but besides being a kludge, that takes around 5 seconds to kick in.  I do want to do something via the drop-down MapTypes menu, which I assume means via the Map Registry, rather than having to create a new button solely for that purpose.

FWIW a working example (with kludge) is at  http://bigsurtrailmap.net/route_metrics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Check the documentation about [Modifying the Map Type Registry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapTypeRegistry) and creating [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#StyledMaps).

A good tool to help you build your custom style is the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use the example under "Base Map Types" to get a sold color map.  I'd actually looked at that page before amongst all the stuff I'd googled, but had not appreciated th e "Base Map Types" example.